# Shape is not showing on paintComponent method using Swing

Tags: java, swing, awt

The shape which is the fillOval is not displaying when running my program. I extended JPanel but it seems there's something wrong since I cannot see the fillOval. Here's my code:

```
public class MovingBall extends JPanel{

public MovingBall(){

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500,700);
    panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    MovingBall movingBall = new MovingBall();
    frame.add(movingBall);
}
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics canvas){
    super.paintComponent(canvas);

    canvas.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    canvas.fillOval(50, 90, 20, 20);

}
```

}

Comment: Did you forget to add a instance of `MovingBall` to the `JFrame`?

Comment: Also, it's generally a bad idea to create a window in the constructor (generally) but especially in a component like this

Comment: @MadProgrammer okay I edited my code. I create and added the MovingBall instance to the JFrame. But still not working.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thnaks for your suggestion. Then where is the best place or best practice to put the window in the main method or in the paintComponent?

Comment: Yep, you updated the code, so it's now in the `main` method which would be preferable.  Now, do you really need `panel`?  Cause you could just replace it with `MovingBall`

Comment: @MadProgrammer ah I see. yeah your right. But I think I'll just Use JPanel movingBall = new MovingBall().

Comment: See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing.

Answer (score 0):

Move the lines before `frame.setSize(500,700);` call

```
MovingBall movingBall = new MovingBall();
frame.add(movingBall);
```

or  call

```
frame.revaliedate();
frame.repaint();
```

after adding